# why not dispay scroll bar in children div

Tags: html, css

```html
<body>
 <div id="parentid" style="position:absolute;width:20%;height:100%;">
  <div id="inputdiv">
   <span >hight:</span>
   <input type="text" id="highlightinput">
  </div>
  <div   id="pollutanttree" style="height:2000px;overflow:auto;">
   test data;
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="position:absolute;left:20%;top:0px;height:100%;width:80%">
           right data;
 </div>
</body>
```

I want show the scroll bar in pollutanttree div'right.but scrool bar show in page's right.

If I move "overflow:auto" from pollutanttree div style to parentid div style, it is almost right: but I don't want input div scroll together.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please specify what you want. It is pretty unclear from your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Hope it worked

```html
<div id="parentid" style="position:absolute;width:20%;height:100%;">
    <div style="height: 32px;line-height: 32px;">
        <span >hight:</span>
        <input type="text" id="highlightinput">
    </div>
    <div   id="pollutanttree" style="position: absolute;top: 32px;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;overflow:auto;">
        <div style="height: 2000px;">
            test data;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks.can I not rely on fixed height and top position?because div for input 's class will change:btn-group-lg/btn-group-sm,and so on....

Comment: No unfortenately i think not

Answer (score 1):

Try this code pen..
For your answer [codepen](http://codepen.io/venumadhavdiv/pen/xRXJoP?editors=1010)

Actually you are giving `height: 2000px` and `overflow: auto` but there is no that much of content in that element, basically when scroll will come means when it exceeding your height.
Hope you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="parentid" style="position:absolute;width:20%;height:100%;">
    <div style="height: 32px;line-height: 32px;">
        <span >hight:</span>
        <input type="text" id="highlightinput">
    </div>
    <div   id="pollutanttree" style="position: absolute;top: 32px;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;overflow:auto;">
        <div style="height: 2000px;">
            test data;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

errrrr,is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you give 2000px height to #pollutanttree which make scrollbar on the body as it's doing. You have to decrease the height of #pollutanttree and putt data in between this. See below code.

```
<body>
    <div id="parentid" style="position:absolute;width:20%;height:100%;">
        <div>
            <span>hight:</span>
            <input type="text" id="highlightinput">
        </div>
        <div id="pollutanttree" style="height:200px;overflow:auto;">
            test data test datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest datatest data;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;left:20%;top:0px;height:100%;width:80%">
           right data;
    </div>
<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>

 <div id="parentid" style="position:absolute;width:20%;height:100%;">
  <div id="inputdiv">
   <span >hight:</span>
   <input type="text" id="highlightinput">
  </div>
  <div   id="pollutanttree" style="height:2000px;overflow:auto;">
   test data;
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="position:absolute;left:20%;top:0px;height:100%;width:80%">

           right data;

 </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```html
<body>

 <div id="parentid" style="position:absolute;width:20%;height:100%;">
  <div id="inputdiv">
   <span >hight:</span>
   <input type="text" id="highlightinput">
  </div>
  <div   id="pollutanttree" style="height:2000px;overflow-y:scroll;">
   test data;
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="position:absolute;left:20%;top:0px;height:100%;width:80%">

           right data;

 </div>


</body>
```